# Why has my syntax colouring changed in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

[image]

My code used to have more colouring for different syntax, I opened my code today and now it isn't highlighting parts of my code like it used to.
The code on the left is my code, the code on the right is the same code but coloured how I remember it. How can I get it back to how it was?

Comment: Yeah it has a .py extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have somehow accidentally changed your Color Theme. You can cycle through them by going to `File -> Preferences -> Color Theme` and selecting the one that you want.